# D3 Dragging circle on x and y axes with horizontal/vertical locks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I'm trying to drag a circle along the x and y-axes but with a lock (don't allow diagonal dragging during the same drag event). I tried to achieve this by drawing two perpendicular rectangles and test whether the mouse is inside one of them, but it doesn't work as it starts jumping around and doesn't lock properly, and there's a problem with the intersection area as well. Has anyone encountered this problem before and has some sort of idea on how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thank you very much in advance!

Code

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)

var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 100)
    .attr("r", 15)
    .style("fill", "purple");

var rectH = svg.insert('rect', 'circle')
    .attr('x', 85)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', 30)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0.25)

var rectV = svg.insert('rect', 'circle')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 85)
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 30)
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0.25)

circle.call(d3.behavior.drag()
     .on('drag', function(d) {
           //  
     })
)
```

Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate better what I want to achieve:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utcemmgp/8)

Basically, during a drag event, the circle should be allowed to only move inside the two rectangles.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate better what I want to achieve: 

    http://jsfiddle.net/utcemmgp/
    Basically, during a drag event, the circle should be allowed to only move inside the two rectangles.

Comment: I have added your comment to the question

Comment: You should probably show some actual effort in coding the drag function. Stack generally doesn't like it when people post an issue and ask them to write the code for them.

Comment: I'm not expecting others to write the code for me, but would rather want to know if there are people around who got into this sort of issue and how they solved it. The posted code was more to make it clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, if you want some theorycraft...

Comment: Updated Fiddle with dragging attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/utcemmgp/8/